# How can we get the original Size of uploaded pics in facebook Graph Api (not profile Picture) Only the Uploaded pics?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, api

I am Getting the images like this ,its working but the size of Image is Small Want to Get the Original Size?
How can i get the Full Size of Uploaded Images?

*GET /{user-id}/photos?type=uploaded*

```
    try 
    {
        if($fbtype =='pages') {
            $response = $fb->get('/'.$fbid.'?fields=picture.type(large),photos.type(uploaded){link,picture,height,width,enum},name,about,phone,feed,emails',$fbtoken);
        } else {
            $response = $fb->get('/'.$fbid.'?fields=picture.type(large),photos.limit(12){name, picture.type(normal)},name,about,feed,email',$fbtoken);
        }
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some of what you have tried already please

Comment: I shared in posts now see

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! NOTE: you should always post code examples of what you have already tried.

Based purely on your non-code post though...

From your request you will have a list of `Photo` nodes. 
It looks like if you GET the photo by ID you have an element called 'images' which will give you a list of all the image files (including dimensions) attached to the `photo`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

Comment: I am using a Face book Graph api to get the data v4.0 I am able to get the profile picture in large size but not able to get the uploaded images in original size here is the code

Comment: try {
   if($fbtype =='pages') {
    $response = $fb->get('/'.$fbid.'?fields=picture.type(large),photos.type(uploaded){link,picture,height,width,enum},name,about,phone,feed,emails',$fbtoken);
   } else {
    $response = $fb->get('/'.$fbid.'?fields=picture.type(large),photos.limit(12){name, picture.type(normal)},name,about,feed,email',$fbtoken);
   }
     } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
         echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
         exit;
     }catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
  
     }

Comment: What you actually want, is `photos.type(uploaded){images}`. That will give you all the available image sizes in an array, you’ll have to then go through them and pick the one you like. (It looks like they are sorted by size descending, so picking the first item out of that array will most likely do. That order is not documented though, so it _might_ change at some point in the future.)